# Windows - Font size on chrome tabs & bookmarks, control panel search bar, files, etc.. is suddenly very small

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, bookmarks

Chrome bookmarks & tab header font sizes have decreased, control panel search bar size has decreased, files application text size has decreased.

I think(?) that this has something to do with the Windows settings, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Currently on Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) For a properly running machine, you can adjust settings.**

Windows 11 (10 too):

Settings, Display, and the Scale Factor.

Increase this.  125% is a middle of the road setting.

In there, you can also access the slider to increase (decrease) text size. Increasing text size is often helpful for applications.

**(2) For a machine that is not properly running**

Altering the registry could have done some damage or damaged the Windows User Profile.

Try a Windows 11 Repair Install and keep everything.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button), download and install then select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(3) Repair fails**

Something or someone has damaged your operating system and / or Windows User Profile.

The easiest way to fix this is to back up your system fully and reinstall Windows 11 from scratch.

Comment: It's not just on Chrome, its w/ multiple programs. It's by default on 200%.

Comment: Increase the text size as I mentioned..  That is the only global setting that will fix all applications.

Comment: Have you been altering the Registry?

Comment: What do you mean by registry?

Comment: I showed the directions for Text Size.  If you have run a command involving regedit.exe  , that is the registry.   Bad changes here can hose your system.  Please let us know

Comment: Or.  If you have run (loaded) a .REG file, that alters the registry as well.

Comment: I suspect you or someone else has damaged your system. You can try a Repair Install, but I have my doubts.  Most likely you will need to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I increased the text size, but the problem is still there.

Comment: I change my answer because something has broken your system. Go to (2) Repair Install and if that fails (3) Back up and reinstall Windows.